In a nested list, where should the "add item" option appear?
Given a list that can be deeply nested (3 or more levels deep), where is the best place to put an "add item" option such that it's clear the depth level at which it's being added? Each level should have a way to add something to it, as the user comes to the list already knowing where exactly they want to add an item (all they have to do is a quick mental scan).
This is what the list looks like:
▼ This is a list
| ▼ That can have
| |    Many many nested items
| |    And I don't know
|
| ▼ Where the user
| |    Wants to put stuff

▼ Since it could
| ▼ Be at
| |    Anywhere
|
| ▼ So having too many
| |    Option can clog up the view

I have thus far thought about these options.
Option 1
Have a small link button (that is not too obtrusive) at the header of the given level, this avoids any ambiguity as to which level it's being added to (maybe shown on hover?).
▼ This is a list [add item]
| ▼ That can have [add item]
| |    Many many nested items [add item]
| |    And I don't know [add item]
|
| ▼ Where the user [add item]
| |    Wants to put stuff [add item]

▼ Since it could [add item]
| ▼ Be at [add item]
| |    Anywhere [add item]
|
| ▼ So having too many [add item]
| |    Option can clog up the view [add item]

Option 2
The "classic". At the end there's a row-like button that when clicked does the same as the previous link would.
▼ This is a list
| ▼ That can have
| |    Many many nested items
| |    And I don't know
| |    [+ Add item]
|
| ▼ Where the user
| |    Wants to put stuff
| |    [+ Add item]
|
|   [+ Add item]

▼ Since it could
| ▼ Be at
| |    Anywhere
| |    [+ Add item]
|
| ▼ So having too many
| |    Option can clog up the view
| |    [+ Add item]
|
|   [+ Add item]

Option 3
At the beginning. This way the vertical height is slightly reduced due to the reduced need of padding between lines, and the depth level is more clear when its header is far away from the button.
▼ This is a list
|   [+ Add item]
| ▼ That can have
| |    [+ Add item]
| |    Many many nested items
| |    And I don't know
|
| ▼ Where the user
| |    [+ Add item]
| |    Wants to put stuff

▼ Since it could
|   [+ Add item]
| ▼ Be at
| |    [+ Add item]
| |    Anywhere
|
| ▼ So having too many
| |    [+ Add item]
| |    Option can clog up the view

It is important to note that the order in the list is a WYSIWYG, so the order is significant. I do not have the data to know if the users might want to always prepend or append any added items, so it would be nice if both cases could be taken into consideration.
EDIT: They would be able to drag these items to rearrange them. The handle appears on its left upon hover, and also there's a whole other view with clickable arrows which might be more intuitive for those that are not as tech-savvy (the majority of these users).

I believe that you could save much space if you simplify the process to add an item in your lists. For example, you could add a button on top saying Add Item or Group and after that the user can select where they want to add it within the architecture, something similar to what happens if you create a folder in your system. Then you will avoid to have extensed data lists and have a clear view.

I believe you want to put it on top of each group, because you can create the item dynamically that once you click on the CTA a prompt appears, and you type the name of the new category. That sounds nic,e however leads you to this kind of problems at one point.
You could add a new category dynamically if you allow the user to use "/" in the cell, for example:
Category A/Subcategory a/New Category

But for that, your users will need a certain level of experience in your app.

Your proposed solution wouldn't really suit this use case as the user expects to be able to point "somewhere" on the tree and be able to add something there. The user doesn't really want to bother too much with this logical tree behind everything, and would rather have it be like a fancier version of a paper list where they can just "magically" add a line between two items wherever and begin typing there.

You're right, my proposal is more for a dropdown list and grouping section rather than a common list. I'll try to find another option for your problem.

Another possibility is to do away with the placement initially: Have a Create button somewhere stable (toolbar or overlay), put the new item somewhere visible (as I assume scrolling will be needed), and encourage the user to drag the item where it belongs.
The number of Add buttons in your wireframes (plus before/after choice) seems daunting...
